# Can we manually throttle the bandwidth of a network interface?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Say I wish to have the interface eth0 to have a very low bandwidth. Is it possible?

As may be evident from the question, I am trying to simulate a network with varying bandwidths.

Note: I am using VirtualBox running Ubuntu to simulate the hosts.

Comment: If it's OK to let the Linux machines do it: http://superuser.com/questions/66574/how-to-throttle-bandwidth-on-a-linux-network-interface

Comment: I think you might do better with this question on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2):

There is a program in the Ubuntu repos that will throttle bandwidth on a process-by-process basis. It's called [trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle). [Here's](https://superuser.com/questions/66574/how-to-throttle-bandwidth-on-a-linux-network-interface) another answer that deals with trickle. Hope that helps with your issue!